# Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.2: Cannot find class 'junit.framework.TestCase' on project build path

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a run configuration for my unit test in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.2, but always get the error

> Cannot find class 'junit.framework.TestCase' on project build path.

The configuration wizard looks like this:

[image]

Where the "test" folder contains several .java files with test methods (i.e. methods with the "@Test" tag).

What do I have to do to make it work?

Comment: `@Test` means JUnit 4, not JUnit 3. Does choosing JUnit 4 as _Test runner_ solve your problem?

Comment: I just figured it out myself: I had to add the library to the project build path, to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

add this to your pom.xml file. then right click your project go to "Maven->updateProject"